# One view controller with multiple views vs multiple view controllers in a bigger view controller

Tags: ios, design-patterns

Let's say A, B, C each is a relatively independent component of the view, with distinctive features, like, 3 different calculators, should I use one view controller with multiple views, or multiple view controllers in a bigger view controller?

[image]

There's this project on github, the MengTo seems to choose for the multiple view controller way: https://github.com/MengTo/Spring

Comment: "should I use one view controller with multiple views, or multiple views in one view controller?" arent those the same things?

Comment: @Fonix yeah spotted that, thanks for pointing out

Comment: Yes You can use Multiple views in One View Controller Or One ViewController can have multiple views. :)

Comment: really depends on what you trying to do, but usually you would go with multiple views in a view controller

Answer (score 0):

You can have one view controller with multiple view controllers, but in order to make a correct decision, I would suggest you to study the [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern. It is essential for understanding how Apple Frameworks work.